# Mysql Circular query with multiple level

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a circular query with join operation but that is limited particular level. but I want to go in depth.

I have following table schema and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usernew` 
(
  `user_id` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `reports_to` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` INT(5) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `usernew` (`user_id`, `reports_to`, `username`, `role_id`) 
VALUES
   ('u1', 'u1', 'user1', 15),
   ('u2', 'u1', 'user2', 15),
   ('u3', 'u2', 'user3', 11),
   ('u4', 'u3', 'user4', 10),
   ('u5', 'u4', 'user5', 8),
   ('u6', 'u5', 'user6', 8),
   ('b1', 'b1', 'buser1', 15),
   ('b2', 'b1', 'buser2', 15),
   ('b3', 'b2', 'buser3', 11),
   ('b4', 'b3', 'buser4', 10),
   ('b5', 'b4', 'buser5', 8),
   ('b6', 'b5', 'buser6', 8);
```

I want all user belongs to role_id 15.I implemented it by using joins but that is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have no enough reputation to add a comment. 
But how about change

```
role_id INT(5) NOT NULL
```

into

```
role_id VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
```

Or change INSERT command with INT type `role_id`?

Maybe `VARCHAR(5) 15` was not equal in `INT(5) 15` type.

Comment: You want to select records which role_id = 15  OR reports_to someone whose role_id = 15 ? Like `select * from usernew where role_id = 15 OR reports_to in (select user_id from usernew where role_id = 15) ;`